# Communication between Tomcat instances

Tags: java, tomcat, chat

I am trying to develop a simple chat application with tomcat 7. Every client will be put in a Map of users and on getting a new message from a client, all users will invoke the Map.

That works fine on ONE Server. But how can I use this scenario on 2 or more instances? Is there a way in Tomcat 7 to inform all instances?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

I think using [JMS](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Ecommerce/jms/) is quite appropriate here.

There are other many other ways to do it even better but it's usually more complicated, this solution is easy and clean for your needs.